# Way to convert from .xls to .xlsm via a batch file or vba?

Tags: vba, batch-file, automation, xlsm

How to I automate the conversion of .xls workbooks to .xlsm?

Answer (score 3):

You can try this code:

```
Sub TrandformAllXLSFilesToXLSM()
Dim myPath As String

myPath = "C:\Excel\"
WorkFile = Dir(myPath & "*.xls")

Do While WorkFile <> ""
    If Right(WorkFile, 4) <> "xlsm" Then
        Workbooks.Open FileName:=myPath & WorkFile
        ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs FileName:= _
        myPath & WorkFile & "m", FileFormat:= _
        xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled, CreateBackup:=False
        ActiveWorkbook.Close
     End If
     WorkFile = Dir()
Loop
End Sub
```

See this [thread](http://www.pcreview.co.uk/forums/convert-xls-xlsm-format-t3613509.html) for more info