# Way to convert from .xlsx to .xlsm?

Tags: vba, automation, xlsx, xlsm

So I found code on here to convert from `.xls` to `.xlsm`, but I would like to convert from `.xlsx` to `.xlsm`.

```
Sub TrandformAllXLSFilesToXLSM()
Dim myPath As String

myPath = "C:\Excel\"
WorkFile = Dir(myPath & "*.xls")

Do While WorkFile <> ""
If Right(WorkFile, 4) <> "xlsm" Then
    Workbooks.Open FileName:=myPath & WorkFile
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs FileName:= _
    myPath & WorkFile & "m", FileFormat:= _
    xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled, CreateBackup:=False
    ActiveWorkbook.Close
 End If
 WorkFile = Dir()
Loop
End Sub
```

[Here is the link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7167207/way-to-convert-from-xls-to-xlsm-via-a-batch-file-or-vba)

Comment: Start with `WorkFile = Dir(myPath & "*.xlsx")`

Comment: Note that `If Right(WorkFile, 4) <> "xlsm" Then` will always be true so it's unnecessary.

Comment: You need to fix the `myPath & WorkFile & "m"`... that would make the extension .xlsxm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Compo said, not close to a batch file or vbs at all.

Added this as a module to mine and and tested it in this particular path. Being a NEWB myself, I am sure there is a cleaner way to do this.

```
Sub XLSX2XLSM()
Dim myPath As String

myPath = "C:\Excel\"
WorkFile = Dir(myPath & "*.xlsx")

Do While WorkFile <> ""
If Right(WorkFile, 4) <> "xlsm" Then
sName = Replace(LCase(WorkFile), ".xlsx", "")
    Workbooks.Open Filename:=myPath & WorkFile
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:= _
    myPath & sName & ".xlsm", FileFormat:= _
    xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled, CreateBackup:=False
    ActiveWorkbook.Close
 End If
 WorkFile = Dir()
 
 
 
 Loop
 
 End Sub
```

Comment: That helped me out! I only tagged the batch file because the previous link tagged it, so that was my bad. Keep up the good work.